# using "href" in if statement

Tags: php

I am new in the world of web development.

I am trying to redirect the user to a link based on the some conditions using IF statement.
but the inside the IF block href is not being recognized.

Any advise so as how can I accomplish this ?

Thanks

EDIT 1

```
<?php   if ($len == 12){
    <a href=" echo $url = "http://www.dddd.in".$row_Recordset1['TRACKING_NO']."1213"; ">track</a>;
    }
    else {
    <a href=" echo $url = "http://www.aaa.in/".$row_Recordset1['TRACKING_NO']."1231"; ">track</a>;
    }
```

?>

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you trying to actually "redirect" the user to another URL or to "show" different URL depending to some conditions?

Comment: @Kostanos I am trying to display different URL depending on some condition. The question has been answered below. Thanks for your time & interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php   
if ($len == 12){
    echo "<a href='http://www.dddd.in/" . $row_Recordset1['TRACKING_NO'] . "1213'> track </a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href='http://www.aaa.in/" . $row_Recordset1['TRACKING_NO'] . "1231'> track </a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is directly opening the webpages. I am trying to make a link to appear for the user to click

Answer (score 2):

Use concatenation. It sure makes things easier.

```
<?php
$url1 = '<a href="http://www.dddd.in/'.$row_Recordset1['TRACKING_NO'].'1213">track</a>';
$url2 = '<a href="http://www.aaa.in/'.$row_Recordset1['TRACKING_NO'].'1231">track</a>';
if ($len == 12) {
    echo $url1;
} else {
    echo $url2;
}
?>
```